# regex php, match string with variable text (letters, numbers, underscore, [])

Tags: php, regex

I am building a simple template engine (in PHP) and I need regex for my loop code, the loop should look something like this:

```
{loop var=menu[0]}
<li><a href="{link}">{text}</a></li>
{/loop}
```

where "menu[0]" can be any string of uppercase or lowercase letters with/without underscores, numbers and box parentheses ([])

```
the '{loop var=', '}' and '{/loop}' always stay the same
```

I'll be using php's preg_match to make the comparison.

my regex so far (which is probably wildly off) is:

```
/[{loop var=][\w\s_0-9\[\]][}]/
```

my php is something like this:

```
function loop($template) {
    preg_match($pattern, $template, $matches);
    foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
        ...
        $var = str_replace(array('{loop var=', '}'), '', $match));
        $data = $this->get($var);
        ...
        $loop_code = str_replace('{' . $var . '}', $data, $loop_code);
        ...
    }
}
```

the input is my template above, the desired output is below

```
<ul>
<li><a href="<?php print $menu[0][0]['link']; ?>"><?php print $menu[0][0]['text']; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php print $menu[0][1]['link']; ?>"><?php print $menu[0][1]['text']; ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

to do this I need preg_match to match any of these strings (in their entirity)

```
{loop var=menu[0]}

{loop var=menu_main}

{loop var=__menu}

{loop var=MenuMain}
```

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Please post a clear sample of the desired **output**.

Comment: just a moment please, working on it

Comment: there you go, my desired input and ouput

Comment: Since this is just a regular expression question, to make your question easier to answer, limit it to the regular expression you have so far and some examples of string you do and don't want to be matched by it. The context why you want it is less relevant. Also take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're after but the following regular expression will match any of the 4 examples you have provided after the = and before the closing }

```
$replacement = '/(menu\[\d]|(m|M)enu(_)?(m|M)ain|__menu))/';
```

I'm just not too sure how you want to use it and what you are going to replace it with.

[image]

If you also want to capture the {loop var=xxxxx }  You'll need this:

```
$replacement = '//({loop var=(menu\[\d]|(m|M)enu(_)?(m|M)ain|__menu)})/';
```

Comment: I'm looking to capture {loop var=something_Here[1]}, not specifically any combination of "menu_main", something like `code` $string = 'dontcaptureth{loop var=menu[0]}dontcapturethis'; preg_match('/{loop var=([][\w]+)}/', $string, $matches); var_dump($matches); `code` which returns the full string (hooray!) and "menu[0]", is there any way to prevent it from returning "menu[0]"? by the way I'm using php's preg_match

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting what you want to capture.  Are you saying you want to identify if the pattern {loop var=xxxxxxxx}  exists in the code but not capture the xxxxxxx (or whatever it is) as a group?

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing square brackets, which indicate only a [single character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Try using a resource such as http://regex101.com/ to test things out.

Rather than mucking with `str_replace` to clean things up afterward, just use the full power of [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg-match):

```
$template = "{loop var=menu[0]}\n<li><a href=\"{link}\">{text}</a></li>\n{/loop}";
$pattern  = "/\{loop var=([\w\[\]]+)\}(.*?)\{\/loop\}/ism";
preg_match($pattern, $template, $matches);
$var_name = $matches[1];
$template_code = $matches[2];
```