# regex php match "{loop var=" \w_[] "}"

Tags: php, regex

I have a string

{loop var=someText}

where someText can be: \w or _ or [ or ]

i have this:

```
/[{loop var=][\w_\[\]][}]/
or
/\b{loop var=\b[\w_\[\]]\b}\b/
```

needs to match entire string of any of below

```
{loop var=MainMenu}
{loop var=menu[0]}
{loop var=Menu_main}
```

Comment: you could just explode on line break, explode on equals

Comment: Does this have anything to do with JavaScript?

Comment: You could improve/comment on your other question.

Comment: I guess if I exploded on the equals I could strpos the {loop var= part and get the strpos of the { and } and then explode, I don't know, I guess regex just seems cleaner

Comment: this comment really doesn't have anything to do with javascript, I just added it because regex is so common in js

Comment: @Nate it's even more common in Perl and Bash, why didn't you add those tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
/{loop var=[][\w]+}/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s2XpmA/3)

When you enclosed the `[{loop var=]` and `[\w_\[\]]` within *non-quantified* character classes, you made the subpatterns that match 1 char, while you need to match *character sequences*.

**Details**:

- `{loop var=`  - a literal character sequence
- `[][\w]+` -  one or more (`+`) chars from the character set - word chars (incl. `_`), `] and`[`
- `}` - a literal `}`

Comment: I ran this: $string = 'asdf{loop var=menu[0]}';
preg_match('/{loop var=([\][\w]+)}/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches); which returns the full string (hooray!) and "menu[0]", is there any way to prevent it from returning "menu[0]"?

Comment: *if you do not need the group, remove the `(` and `)`* - I edited the answer.

Comment: Is the problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246739/regex-php-match-string-with-variable-text-letters-numbers-underscore the same? I can't make out much from your previous question. This one is straight-forward.

Comment: i'll delete the other one and put that information here, could you re-open this one if I do that?

Comment: summing up what I'm trying to do is capture the opening 'loop tag' in a template regardless of the variable it points to, then replace the tags within the loop with the variable's data